# apache shiro using Hashing Credentials can not make login successfully

Tags: jsf, shiro

I am using shiro, and I use hashing credential as my credential.

here is my shiro.ini configuration:

```
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 1024
realmA.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher
securityManager.realms = $realmA
```

below is how I generate the salt and hashed password:

```
RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
ByteSource salt = rng.nextBytes();
String passwordsalt=salt.toBase64();
String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash(user.getPassword(),
                    salt, 1024).toBase64();
user.setPassword(hashedPasswordBase64);
user.setByteTabSalt(passwordsalt);
dao.createUser(user);
```

this is the Realm I extended:

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(
            AuthenticationToken authToken) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordToken token = (UsernamePasswordToken) authToken;
        User user = dao.getForUsername(token.getUsername());
        if (user != null) {
            SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(
                    user.getEmail_account(), user.getPassword(), getName());
            ByteSource salt = new SimpleByteSource(Base64.decode(user
                    .getByteTabSalt()));
            info.setCredentialsSalt(salt);
            return info;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

but when I use my new generated account to login, I never success.
the debug result is I got the user object correctly. any idea?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HashedCredentialsMatcher` is an older Shiro concept.  Instead, I highly recommend using the `PasswordService` and it's corresponding `PasswordMatcher` as documented here:

https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/PasswordService.html

Comment: Thank you. so what about the relationship between credentialsMatcher and PasswordMatcher?

Comment: @neptune the `PasswordMatcher` is an implementation of `CredentialsMatcher` that just delegates to the `PasswordService`.  You still need it - it just acts as a bridge from the general-purpose `CredentialsMatcher` interface to the password-specific `PasswordService`.

Comment: @Recurse how is this answer downvoted?  That makes no sense.  The answer itself is valid and useful - any gripes you may have with documentation are a separate concern and should be voiced on the user list.  Or better yet, given that Shiro is an open source project, we'll gladly accept patches for any help you wish to offer.  (We really would love any help you might be willing to offer).

Comment: @Recurse also, what do you mean almost completely undocumented.  The linked JavaDoc is extremely thorough - it even gives multiple code samples!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I need to set the credentials matcher at my custom EnvironmentLoaderListener:

```
    WebEnvironment environment = super.createEnvironment(pServletContext);
    RealmSecurityManager rsm = (RealmSecurityManager) environment
            .getSecurityManager();
    HashedCredentialsMatcher matcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
    matcher.setHashAlgorithmName(Sha256Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME);
    matcher.setHashIterations(1024);
    matcher.setStoredCredentialsHexEncoded(false);
```